# Docker Port Forwarding and Privileged Flag not working

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dedicated-server

This is my first question :-). I host all my services through docker on my actual root server, which works fine and is managed through rancher. But now I want to move my services to another host from a new provider, which resolves to be harder then I thought :-).

Here is my problem: 
When ever I start a new docker container with port forwarding on the new host I 'm not able to reach it. I tried to create and start a new nginx container with the following command:

`docker run -p 80:80 -d nginx:latest`

Using curl resolves to the following behaivor:

- From my PC im not able to curl on server_ip
- From my server (outside of the container) I'm not able to curl on localhost
- From inside the container **I'm able** to curl on localhost

I don't know if it is related, but I'm also not able to create a privileged container. It resolves to the following error:

```
root@server:/home/michael# docker run --privileged -p 80:80  nginx:latest
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "operation not permitted"
docker: Error response from daemon: transport is closing.
```

My old server (Netcup):

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64)
```

My new server (Medialocation):

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 x86_64)
```

So my question is: How do I get my port forwarding working and what can I do to start a privileged container?

Comment: It's pretty suspicious that your new server running Ubuntu on a Debian kernel. Are you sure it's not a LXC or OpenVZ guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. Like @jordanm mentioned, my server is a LXC guest, which needed additional privileges from the provider to work properly with docker.

Thank you jordan.